# Поведение при вложенных транзакциях Spring Framework

Tags: spring

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю поведение вложенных транзакций в Spring Framework.

Предположим, есть два метода:

```
@Transactional
public void methodOne() {
    // 1. do work
    methodTwo();
    // 2. do work         
}

@Transactional
public void methodTwo() {
   // throw RuntimeExceptiotion        
}
```

1. Если у `methodTwo()` указать `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW`, то транзакция внутри `methodTwo()` откатиться, а участки кода `// 1. do work` и `// 2.do work` внутри `methodOne()` успешно выполняться.
2. Если у `methodTwo()` указать `propagation = Propagation.NESTED`, то транзакция внутри `methodTwo()` откатиться, а внутри `methodOne()` успешно выполниться только участок кода `// 1. do work`. Участок кода `// 2.do work` также откатится.

Answer (score 0):

Транзакция откатится тогда, и только тогда, кода будет выброшен RuntimeException. Да, можно определить свой ErrorHandler и откатываться в других случаях, но по-умолчанию Hibernate реагирует только на RuntimeException. Тут понимать надо не когда транзакция откатится, а как она будет выполняться. В случае указания propogation = Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW на методе methodTwo, это будет означать лишь то, что все действия в этом методе будут выполняться в рамках новой транзакции всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы корректно ответить на ваш вопрос необходимо сначала определить, являются ли эти методы частью одного класса или разных.

Предположим, эти методы находятся в одном классе:

1. Будет создана только одна физическая транзакция при вызове метода `methodOne()`. В таком случае при вызове `methodTwo()` все изменения должны откатиться
2. Аналогичное поведение, как в п.1

Предположим, эти методы находятся в разных классах:

1. Будут созданы 2 физические транзакции. Откат транзакции в `methodTwo()` не повлияет на откат `// 1. do work` и `// 2.do work` в `methodOne()`
2. Будет создана одна физическая транзакция, а также Save Point (точка сохранения) в момент вызова `methodTwo()` (работает только с JDBC). Вы описали верное поведение, то есть `// 1. do work` выполнится, а `// 2.do work` не выполнится

Подробнее [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)